# understanding OOP classes in python using a real case and the Dog case, OOP structure, and OOP inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

2 basic beginner level questions on OOP and inheritance:

1. Is this the correct OOP way to use classes? `Job()` makes sense in OOP, but does `Process()'
2. Inheritance, can python work in this way, am I expecting too much of python?

Firstly I can program a script, do A, then B, then C etc.

However, I want to be more OOP oriented moving up to classes, but I'm struggling to understand. I am neuron diverse, so I learn/understand in a different way to most, so googling isn't helping me understand.

So, I understand OOP in terms of say the classic Dog() object.

But here's my use case:

I have a `job()` (such as a task) it has a `job number`, `prefix`, and a `site_code`

In this case it is clear that these variable should be assigned to the object:

```
class Job():
    def __init__(self, prefix, job_number, site_code):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.job_number = job_number
        self.site_code = site_code

    def get_job_name(self)
        job_name = self.prefix + self.job_number
        return job_name

    # I would like to assign job_name to the object automatically as the Job() is created
```

So, with this defined

```
current_job = Job('prefix', '55', 'ABC')

name = current_job.job_name
```

I would then like to pass the job through a certain process, I know I could define this within the `Job()` object through several `def()` but to stay in OOP I would like to assign a new class,lets call it `class Process():`

This takes the `Job()` object and puts it through the process with some options

Now I could put it like this

```
class Process(Job):
    def __init__(self, prefix, job_number, site_code, flag_a, flag_b):
        super().__init__(prefix, job_number, site_code)
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.job_number = job_number
        self.site_code = site_code
        self.job_name = job_name
        self.flag_a = flag_a
        self.flag_b = flag_b
```

But can I put it through like this so that the attributes of the `Job()` are inherited automatically? This way I simply pass the `Job()` object.

```
class Process(Job):
    def __init__(self, prefix, job_number, site_code, flag_a, flag_b):
        super().__init__(prefix, job_number, site_code)
        self.prefix = Job.prefix
        self.job_number = Job.job_number
        self.site_code = Job.site_code
        self.job_name = Job.job_name

        self.flag_a = flag_a
        self.flag_b = flag_b
```

And run the code

```
current_job = Job('prefix', '55', 'ABC')
processed_job = Process(Job=current_job, flag_a=True, flag_b=False)
```

So, 2 questions:

1. Is this the correct OOP way to use classes? `Job()` makes sense in OOP, but does `Process()'
2. Inheritance, can python work in this way, am I expecting too much of python?

As I said, I am neuron diverse (dyslexic) so I would appreciate a basic straight forward answer. Perhaps in the `Dog()` example the `Process()` could be `Vets()`, the `Dog()` goes through a series of procedures every time it is sent to the `Vets()` depending on the options, e.g.

```
spot = Dog()
dog_checked = Vets(patient=Dog, proceedure='checkup')
```

I've tried to keep this as simple as possible, giving a real case and a theoretical case. Simple explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's a little confusing to me the way you've written your `Process` class in the question, as you're not using the `class` statement in the normal place. You seem to be showing a call of the class instead? I'm not sure if that's just a typo (since you do show `class Process()` elsewhere), or if that's actually what you're trying to run?

Comment: Where I say `And run the code` are two lines to 1. create the `Job()` and 2. send the `Job()` to the `Process()`.  If I seem to be miss understanding something then please explain my error, I'd rather learn this once correctly than have to relearn it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking about the two code blocks above that. They both show the body of a class, but the statement at the top is a call to the class, not a `class` statement. I'm pretty sure that's not what you're actually running or you'd be getting syntax errors all over the place.

Comment: I understand the `Job()` as an object and the `Process()` as another object. Take the Dog/Vet example. The `Dog()` has a `self.breed`, `self.name` etc. The `Vet()` has a `self.address` but if the `Dog()` is sent to the `Vet()` then a procedure can take place, e.g. `def checkup():`. The code I've posted may need editing, but was meant as a starting point, I thought it ran, I'll double check.

Comment: @Blckknght ah, I forgot the `class` definition, is that better?
I see where I screwed up, ok, that should be fixed, sorry, you see what a muddle I can get myself in!